# Object orient programming and DAO design pattern

Tags: oop, dao

I am new to java programming and am trying to understand the correct way to implement the DAO design pattern. Here's an example, I have an itemCatalog class that includes the populateItemCatalog and searchitemCatalog methods. The item catalog was implemented using an array of type item objects.

Now I want to switch to an DAO design to access the same data from an ms-access database. My question is what becomes of these methods now as the DAO is doing the searching of the database. Do I modify them to return the DTO from the DAO. Hope my question is clear. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say; now you want to fetch the same data from a different DB. Such cases DAO pattern suits ideally.

```
    public interface ItemCatalogDAO extends GenericDAO<DTO, String> {
   public DTO populateCatalog(String id); 
       public searchCatalog(String x);
     }
```

Now your implementing classes will have to implement above (sample) interface. Just make sure that you design the interface in such a way that it can be used by all implementing classes.

So as you asked can you return DTO. Yes, you should return DTO or list of DTO as per your requirement. It's good practice to return an Object from your DAO. This way you abstract your implementation and it supports use of generics as well.

Comment: Would my itemCatalog look something like this:
    public void populateItemcalalog()throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        DAO dao = DAO.getDAO();
        ArrayList <Item> itemCatalog = dao.getitemCatalog();

Comment: ArrayList<Item> itemCatalog = dao.getitemCatalog(); Yes, you should return object like this. Just make sure that you keep all DB related logic in the DAO class.

Answer (score 1):

Typically here is how it works.

You implement a DAO interface for your objects. 
In your case CatalogDao.

This should have all the required data access methods.

Now, the idea behind the DAO pattern is that you can have multiple implementations of the same.

In your case you will have a MS-Access implementation of it. This should hide all the database specific logic, and should return POJOs.

DTO is typically something different. In its usual sense, it means the object that is used in client - server communication. For example your POJO could get converted to xml or json. when called from a client.

This is different altogehter.

In short, DAO hides the db implementation details from your application layer so that the application layer can deal directly with java objects.

```
public interface ItemCatalogDao{
  ItemCatalog searchItemCatalog(Long itemId)
}
```

And one possible implementation could be

```
public class ItemCatalogDaoMsImpl implements ItemCatalogDao{

  public ItemCatalogDaoMsImpl(){
    //do your initialization code here , such as getting connection etc
}
  public ItemCatalog searchItemCatalog(Long itemId){
   //write your sql code here
}
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sajit - I am still a bit confuse, can you help me out with an example using my itemCalalog class?

Comment: Hey thanks for your patience and advise it is much appreciated, as I mentioned I am really new to java. So essentially what you are saying is that I would no longer have a itemCatalog class but an itemCatalogDao class (interface) correct?

Comment: Not sure of your class names.. But yes. If item is your java bean representing the model, the you you won't be having itemcatalog but the itemcatalogdao interface. Sorry about confusing with class naming